# What does a high Hall Effect Parameter mean in MPD thrusters?

Tags: advanced-propulsion, ion-thruster, thrust

MagnetoPlasmaDynamic Thrusters are plasma thrusters in which the acceleration of the fluid (plasma) is carried in a electromagnetic way. The electric field and the lorentz force are the primary causes of this acceleration. Otherwise, because of the presence of an electric and magnetic field there's a perpendicular component causing a flow of electrons (externally seen as current) which is called Hall effect. What is the main implication of a large Hall effect parameter in MPD?. Remember that the hall parameter is the angle between the j/sigma and the total electric field (E*=E+uxB).